# Passing the tracking variable as void inside a method's argument

Tags: ios, swift

So as I'm working myself through Swift as a beginner I saw this convention of

`{ something in`

for certain method arguments. As far as I understand, this is because some arguments give you a variable/constant which can be used in the following code block to track changes in the state of the object. I've seen it when adding a completion to a `UIViewPropertyAnimator`-object where you can track the progress of the completion like so:

```
animation.addCompletion({ progress in
    if progress == .end {
        // do something
    }
})
```

Now my question is what is meant by this (image below)? I clearly understand what is done inside the block but I don't really understand what this cryptic "`action -> Void in`" is used for. Is it because an action is trackable but actually isn't being tracked inside the block so you declare it like "`action -> Void`"?

[image]

Comment: its closure that UIAlertAction takes `((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?`

Answer (score 0):

The `action -> void` in this case tells you that the parameter that is expected is  a closure, basically a function that is given as a parameter. More about it in the official documentation: [Closure Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html).

Your code for the `UIAlertAction` will look like that:

```
UIAlertAction(title: "Title", style: .default) { action in
   // The Code that should run once the action is triggered.
}
```

The parameter action that is passed into that closure-function is the `UIAlertAction` itself.